# What tool to use for finding duplicated Ada code due to copy&paste

Tags: code-analysis, ada, code-duplication

I'm looking for a tool for finding duplicated code due to copy&paste programming to be run over a large Ada codebase. I suppose that Ada support in the tool is important for detecting more than the trivial text similarities, that is, ignore layout or identifier difference, etc.

The tools that I have found with Ada support are the following:

1. Clone Doctor, commercial product with support for several languages, including Ada. http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Clone/index.html
2. ConQAT: commercially supported open source product that includes a CloneDetection tool with Ada support since September 2011 http://conqat.cs.tum.edu/index.php/CloneDetectionTutorial

Have you tried these tools? Am I missing any other one of interest? Is the language support really significant or a general text tool would be enough? What is your experience with code duplication detection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AdaCore have done some [related work](http://blog.adacore.com/a-usable-copy-paste-detector-in-few-lines-of-python) recently

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of CloneDR.  Read the following understanding my bias.

It is important to understand the differences in the detection methods of clone detection tools, and the quality of the results as a consequence.

ConQAT is a representative of what are called "token based" detectors.  They match sequences of language tokens (operators, identifiers, brackets, keywords etc.)  The good news is they are pretty fast (that isn't a big issue; you don't run clone detection every 30 seconds, once a week is enough).  They will find some clones that are near-misses, in the sense that another identifier or constant is substituted for an identifier in a clone.   The bad news is that they don't understand the structure of your code and consequently want to report things like

```
 } void ID ( ID
```

as clones.   This is defeated by making the detectors only hunt for very long sequences of tokens (typically 30 or more), which means token-based detectors cannot find small but interesting clones without also drowning you in false positives like the above.

CloneDR operates by parsing the code (even for Ada) just like a compiler, building abstract syntax trees, and matching the trees up to a point of difference.   It cannot propose a clone that crosses structure boundaries in silly ways.    It will find near misses of the same kind as the token based detectors, but it goes beyond this.  CloneDR will find consistent substitutions ("anti unifiers") which means clones can be explained by a small number of parameters that have been used in many places in the clone, and it will find variations in the code in which the mismatches are larger than a single token, e.g., expressions, statements, declarations, even blocks.  So it produces fewer false positives and better answers.  [Independent research reports that compare types of clone detectors, specifically including CloneDR, agree with this analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.4429&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

There is more detailed discussion at the Clone Doctor link you listed above.  You can see examples of detected clones for many languages (but we don't have an Ada report on the web site).

EDIT March 19, 2012:

Now you can [download an eval copy of an Ada95 CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/RegisterEval.html).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I have reported both tools to management, the final choice is not mine. I have also added another option, which I don't know if it is viable: combining these two tools for adding Ada support to the former: CloneDigger as detector - http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/documentation.html and Avatox as abstract syntax tree generator -
http://www.mckae.com/avatox.html If someone has some insight about this option, please comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Gneuromante: an Ada XML AST output may work with CloneDigger.  I don't think that the (Avatox) ASIS output is an AST although you may be able to extract something AST-like from it, shaped in a form that CloneDigger wants.  So this option is really a question of how much work do you want to do to get a detection answer.  On a different aspect of CloneDigger, as far as I know it does not compute *clone sets* but rather *clone pairs*.  This doesn't matter for 90% of the clones (which come in pairs), but when you N instances of cloned code, you get O(N^2) clone pairs rather than one clone set.

Answer (score 0):

Ira Baxter has a good description.

Token-based clone detection tools tend to be good enough for our purpose, which is usually to get a quick overview of how bad code duplication is in a body of source code we haven't seen before, and how duplication is distributed across that code.

In particular, we are happy with [CCFinderX](http://www.ccfinder.net/), because it has a nice visualization frontend.
However, it's buggy, unmaintained, and the code has been released but without any license statement.

It has language specific preprocessors for some languages, but we often just disable them (they are buggy as well).

If you need better accuracy, you know exactly the language you need to parse (e.g. with C or C++, this is not always the case), and you can find a tool that parses exactly that language (which is also an issue with C and C++), a parsing-based approach may be better, as Ira writes.